# Using #temp to work around Reporting Services blocking issue

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssrs, temporary-tables

Having utterly failed to resolve why a perfectly acceptable but admitidly large stored procedure was suffering the blocking process `lck_m_s` when called via a report in SQL Reporting Services I have been forced to implement the following as a work around.

1. Create a #temp table
2. Insert the exisiting stored procedure into the

   ## temp table
3. Select from #temp
4. Delete #temp

This process results in a report generation time of 10 seconds vs the 2 minutes I was suffering when calling the origional report stored procedure via reporting servces.

This to me feels like a dirty hack but it works and works well from the perspecitive of the users.

**Is there a better method I could have used?**

Edit:

> I'd like to get some more information on this blocking issue since
>   that is the root issue. –  Zane

More info here
[Reporting Services TempDB lock blocking report generation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61134/reporting-services-tempdb-lock-blocking-report-generation)
However, the issue mysteriously reappeared and then as I was finishing the hack implementation it disappeared, again!

> Did you try using snapshot isolation? –  Jon Seigel

Yes, but it had no affect, still blocking seen similar to this issue [Shared locks taken under Read Committed Snapshot Isolation (RCSI)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39628/getting-lck-m-s-on-read-committed-snapshot-isolation)

> Did you try using the temp table in the stored procedure? –  Shawn Melton

No, I don't understand how to implement it that way round, why would it be of benefit?

Comment: Did you try using the temp table in the stored procedure?

Comment: I'd like to get some more information on this blocking issue since that is the root issue.